# How to use sfinae to exclude types for which a function is defined?

Tags: c++, sfinae, decltype, trailing-return-type

Considering how the comma expression in a `decltype()` trailing return type can be used to check if a function can be applied:

```
template <class A>
auto f(A a) -> decltype(check_if_possible(a), return_type(a))
```

How can I negate the part before the comma to exclude cases in which `check_if_possible(a)` is defined?

Context:
`f()` is an overloaded function for different `A`. I want to resolve an ambiguous overload between two implementations. One of them uses `check_if_possible(a)`, the other works in cases where this cannot be applied to `a`.

Edit:
Using `std::enable_if` and related things is welcome as well, but I would like to avoid additional helper functions / templates, because there are several functions similar to `f()` with different enable criteria.
If this is not possible, then that is an answer as well ;)

Comment: since C++20, you can use `requires`.

Answer (score 5):

> How can I negate the part before the comma to exclude cases in which check_if_possible(a) is defined?

I don't know a way, but...

> Context: f is an overloaded function for different A. I want to resolve an ambiguous overload between two implementations. One of them uses check_if_possible(a), the other works in cases where this cannot be applied to a.

I usually write a `f()` function for both cases that demand a couple of `f_helper()` functions receiving an additional argument.

For example

```
template <typename A>
auto f (A && a)
 { return f_helper(std::forward<A>(a), 0); }
```

Observe the last argument: `0`, it's a `int`

Then you can write the `check_if_possible()` version, receiving an additional `int`

```
template <typename A>
auto f_helper (A a, int) -> decltype(check_if_possible(a), return_type(a))
 { /* ... */ }
```

and a generic version, always enabled, receiving an additional `long`

```
template <typename A>
auto f_helper (A a, long)
 { /* ... */ }
```

This way, when `A` support `check_if_possible()`, both `f_helper()` are enabled but the specific version is preferred because `0` is a `int`, the specific version receive an additional `int` (exact match) and the generic an additional `long` (`int` is convertible to `long` but isn't an exact match).

When `A` doesn't support `check_if_possible()`, only the generic `f_helper()` is available.

Comment: Thank you. I was considering priority tags as an alternative. While your answer works in the given context, I will leave the question open as it is still unanswered how (or whether) sfinae can disable functions when a certain call can be made.

Comment: @Aaron - Yes... I too am curious to know if it's possible in a simpler way.

Answer (score 1):

You could rely on C++17's [`constexpr` `if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) in order to provide the two different implementations:

```
template<class A>
auto f(A a) {
   if constexpr (supportsExpression(a)) {
      // implementation that uses the check_if_possible(a) expression
      // ...
      check_if_possible(a);
      // ...
   } else {
      // implementation that doesn't use the check_if_possible(a) expression
      // ...
   }
}
```

Then, provide two overloaded function templates for `supportsExpression()`:

```
// uses SFINAE
template<typename T>
constexpr auto supportsExpression(T&& arg) ->
   decltype((void)check_if_possible(arg), bool{})
{
   return true;
}

// fallback
template<typename... T>
constexpr bool supportsExpression(T&&...) { return false; }
```

The first overload will be – due to SFINAE – discarded if the expression `check_if_possible(arg)` wouldn't compile.

If the first overload is not discarded from the overloaded set due to SFINAE, we end up with two suitable overloads when calling `supportsExpression()` in `f()`. In this case, however, the non-variadic function template is preferred over the variadic one, i.e., the one that returns `true` (the type `A` supports the expression).